EKG active filter designs with single power supply
This is my beginners attempt at designing a EKG. I have printed out the PCB and attached all components to it to test it out. What I have observed are the following:
1. The outputs Vout1 as well as Vout2 get completely saturated.
2. PLI (Power line interference) does not seem to be removed, inspite of the presence of the bandwidth filter.
Some of the unambiguities I had during designing were:
1. How exactly are the OpAmps implemented using a single power supply? (From what I've been able to gather so far, the input should be biased with a reference voltage (half of the power voltage), which I have marked as Vref on the schematic).
2. Should the active filters have a feedback loop, in order to control gain, thus avoiding saturation?
3. Is RLD (Right Leg Drive) an absolutely essential part of the circuit? or does it simply provide more sharpness and clarity to the signal?
I apologize, if there are any unambiguities in the thread. I would appreciate it, if someone could provide some insights, when it comes to designing an EKG or filters in general for that matter.


C10 should be wired between the 10k 's and ground.

Have you tried with ECGp and ECGn wired to Vref ?

You "should" have also resistors (100 kOhm ?) between the inputs of the INA333 and Vref ...

The filtering/preamp stage is DC-coupled, so you must provide a way to DC offset the ECGn and ECGp inputs into the center of the amp's operating range (i.e. the REF voltage). If you don't want to build a full RLD circuit, feed the REF voltage to the ECGn and ECGp inputs through 100k resistors. Or, feed REF through a 100k resistor to a third ECG electrode on the right leg.

@Mark Leavitt Thank you very much for your inputs. But I would like a further clarification. Wouldn't the DC offset fed into ECGn and ECGp just cancel out? As the op amp is a differential amplifier. And what would be the purpose of a 100k resistor between the inputs?

@Antonio51 Isn't C10 there to further remove noises present in the power supply? Why should be between the 10k and the ground?

It is at the input+ node of the opa356 that the noise must be removed ... Better solution, because this node is used as "reference".
